# Adding values in ng-model does not work

Tags: angularjs

Can I make the code in `ng-model` work anyhow, as I need to show the first as well as the last name?

What I basically want is to turn this

```
{{currentInventory.assigned.first_name + ' ' + currentInventory.assigned.last_name}}
```

into this:

```
ng-model="currentInventory.assigned.first_name + ' ' + currentInventory.assigned.last_name"
```

Comment: this wont work. if you just want to display these values:
<p>{{currentInventory.assigned.first_name}} {{currentInventory.assigned.last_name}}</p> ...

ng-model wants to bind a variable, assigning ng-model="currentInventory.assigned.first_name + ' ' + currentInventory.assigned.last_name" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you confusing `ng-model` and `ng-bind` ?

`ng-model` purpose is to bind a field to a scope variable.
`ng-bind` purpose is to display a value by evaluating an angular expression like yours

You could also do something as follow :

```
<textarea ng-model="yourmodel" ng-init="yourmodel="currentInventory.assigned.first_name + ' ' + currentInventory.assigned.last_name" ng-bind="yourmodel"></textarea>
```

That:

- binds `scope.yourmodel` to your field
- init its value with your expression
- displays it with `ng-bind` (or `ng-value` or other..)

Comment: ng-bind is uni-directional: it is a read-only value. ng-model is bi-directional: the value can be updated (on the front-end, usually inside a form)

Comment: @Tone Well yeah obvisouly, am I saying the contrary here ?

Comment: firstly it's not obvious to an angularjs novice. Secondly, I'm simply adding to your answer in the spirit of learning so have the grace to accept it as such.

Comment: @Tone ha ok sorry but your comment was ambiguous... I though I said something wrong, don't stress.

Answer (score 0):

in controller :

```
$scope.text = $scope.currentInventory.assigned.first_name + ' '+ $scope.currentInventory.assigned.last_name;
```

in HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" />
```

Append the value in conroller and send that value to model.